# HackerRank problem to get MinCostProblem where you have cost array and tagList matrix

Tags: data-structures

Given an array of cost where cost[i] is the cost to create ith problem and given a tagList matrix where tagList[i][j] = 1 means ith problem contains jth tag else tagList[i][j]=0. Get minimum cost such that all tags are covered. How to implement getMinCost function?

I T ried greedy approach of picking minimum cost from priorityqueue and add it to my resultset. Keep doing this until all tagList are covered. But this approach fails for some test cases. How to solve this problem

Comment: Please provide the code and test case for which it fails.

Comment: The test cases were hidden

Comment: Can you share your approach

Answer (score 0):

1. Initialize an array `dp` of length 2^k (where k is the number of tags), where `dp[S]` represents the minimum cost to cover all tags in the set S. Set all elements of `dp` to infinity except `dp[0]`, which is set to 0.
2. For each problem i, compute the set of tags S_i that it covers. For each tag set S in dp such that S_i is a subset of S, update dp[S] as `min(dp[S], dp[S-S_i] + cost[i])`.
3. Return `dp[2^k-1]`, which represents the minimum cost to cover all tags.

```
    def getMinCost(cost, tagList):
        n = len(cost)
        k = len(tagList[0])
        dp = [float('inf')] * (1 << k)
        dp[0] = 0
        for i in range(n):
            S_i = 0
            for j in range(k):
                if tagList[i][j]:
                    S_i |= 1 << j
            for S in range(1 << k):
                if S_i & S == S:
                    dp[S] = min(dp[S], dp[S-S_i] + cost[i])
        return dp[(1 << k) - 1]
```